# Does Python's pickle work in r+b mode?

Tags: python, pickle

Assume I have used pickle.dump to store an integer value and I want to update that integer by adding 1. The following code works:

```
with open('../CONFIG.txt', 'rb') as ofile:
    value = pickle.load(ofile)

with open('../CONFIG.txt', 'wb') as ofile:
    pickle.dump(value + 1, ofile, protocol=2)
```

But once I use r+b mode it doesn't:

```
with open('../CONFIG.txt', 'r+b') as ofile:
    value = pickle.load(ofile)
    pickle.dump(value + 1, ofile, protocol=2)
```

Why does the second code not work? Is there a way to update the file contents without opening the file twice?

Comment: You're writing the new pickle after the old. You'd have the same issue with `read` and `write`.

Comment: "Is there a way to update the file contents without opening the file twice?" -- why do you not want to open it twice?

Comment: It seems repetitive to open the file twice. Its also a general learning question - I want to understand why the above code doesn't work the way I expected.

Comment: Same reason opening any file in a read/write mode and doing a `read()` followed by a `write(...)` will append the contents rather than overwrite them: the read (`pickle.load()`) moves the position pointer to the end of the file, and the write (`pickle.dump()`) goes from there.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. The word 'dump' for me invoked the idea that the entire file was overwritten by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *Update 2:*

If you do need to read and write pickled data with the same file, it's better to do them separately, once with `'r'` and then with `'w'` modes. The act of "opening a file" is not nearly as expensive as reading or writing to it. Opening a file, aka getting a *file handle*, is reasonably fast.

And if you're concerned about the size of the data being read/written the `'r+b'` mode, the size in RAM is more of a concern that reading/writing. You aren't skipping that step for time, cpu cycles or disk actions.

There's also *readability*. Consider your original versions with `'rb'` and `'wb'` (4 lines, easily understandable) vs 6 in the "do it in one block" method. The explicit `seek(0)` and `truncate()` are what would have occurred in a separate `'wb'` block anyway. Probably affects performance too. The one-block method has no benefits and is worse for reading and error prone for writing - needed 3 edits to fix an issue the one-block method created. :-/

#### *Original answer:*

As mentioned by @glibdud in the comments, after you do `pickle.load()`, the file pointer is moved to the end.

If you want to write data back to the file using the `'r+b'` mode, then use [`ofile.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to modify the position of the cursor. In this case, putting [`ofile.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) moves the cursor back to the start of the file.

```
>>> with open('CONFIG.txt', 'r+b') as ofile:
...     value = pickle.load(ofile)
...     print value
...     # re-position the cursor to the start of the file before dumping new data
...     ofile.seek(0)
...     pickle.dump(value + 1, ofile, protocol=2)
...     # truncate anything left in the file if the prev pickled data was larger
...     ofile.truncate()
...
3
>>> 
>>> # let's read again to see
...
>>> with open('CONFIG.txt', 'r+b') as ofile:
...     value = pickle.load(ofile)
...     print value
...
4
>>>
```

#### *Update 1 & 3:*

Wrt the comment by @user2357112 about truncating the file: <strike>I don't think it's needed. I pickled dumped a longer text and then had it write just an int, it seems to have overwritten correctly. Maybe the dump file needs to be bigger to verify if there's an issue; or the ascii format of protocol 0 being susceptible to it vs binary format of protocols >= 1.</strike> *Correction:* The extra data is still in the file, as mentioned in the comments. So [`file.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate) is needed. See comments below. Fortunately, in the default usage (no arguments), it truncates to the current position.

Comment: And then truncate the file so you don't leave any garbage at the end after your new pickle if it happens to be shorter than the old.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of that. I assumed that it would overwrite fully. In my edit/update above, it does look that way.

Comment: It loads fine because the pickle format includes an end-of-pickle marker, so unpickling from the file doesn't try to read the extra garbage, but it's still there, wasting disk space.

Comment: Great answer. Can you elaborate on why you think reading and writing them separately with `rb` and `wb` is better. Getting a file handle is easy enough that this isn't a big issue, but I'm (politely) curious as to your thinking.

Comment: I think I've already answered that part - nothing is gained by doing it in one block and a lot is lost (read the latest edit): Consider your original versions with `'rb'` and `'wb'` (4 lines, easily understandable) vs 6 in the "do it in one block" method. The explicit `seek(0)` and `truncate()` are what would have occurred in a separate `'wb'` block anyway.